# jmeter not sending the parameters mentioned in the http request

Tags: jmeter

I am having some problems with jmeter. When i try to submit values to a form they don't appear there in the updated list. I am trying to check a feature of adding restaurants of a web app based on a local server right now. In the view results tree it appears successful. I put the id of the parameter by getting it from the page source and then write the value for it in the value column. Can please someone guide me through the process?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter actually dose not cares about what page it has got back as response, any response with status 200 will make it successful. It is users responsibility to make sure correct response is retrieved. So when you submit a form through JMeter to add a restaurant, make sure the response for it has success confirmation of restaurant added.

Answer (score 0):

Following SSujesh answer, If for example you will do a false login in drupal - you still get 200OK ...

Try and find out if there is a key that is generated per user that you need to extract, for example:
Druapl will issue a form_build_id that you will need to extract (every time you initiate a login) and then pass while you do the post request...

Same goes to aspx.

gl,
Refael