# Access denied when trying to simulate login on a drupal site using jmeter

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, jmeter

I am trying to do load test on a site built using Drupal7. 
Here are the steps I am trying to simulate by jmeter [version 2.9]:
1. Navigate to landing page
2. Click on Login link
3. Enter credentials and Click Login Button

The issue I am facing is at the step 3 where login button is clicked after entering the user credentials. At this step, the response (html as seen in View Results tree) shows Access Denied page. The response code is 403 - Forbidden. I have taken care of the dynamic value of form_build_id too by using a Regular expression extractor and can see that the value is being captured correctly and being passed in the Login step POST request.

Tried so far:
1. I have also looked at this [existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175559/jmeter-not-sending-the-parameters-mentioned-in-the-http-request/19208636#19208636)
2. Tried with both Redirect automatically & Follow redirect options in Http sampler
3. Simulated same steps in drupal.org site and there the login happens correctly. Page title has the username

Answer (score 1):

Do you use a cookie manager? If not, this is the reason.
You can try this Drupal module that should takes care of all of the Drupal handshake: http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/73566-blazemeter-drupal-module

Answer (score 0):

I believe that it's connected to [Basic Authentication](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter). Your application expects browser containing following header:

```
Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Where XXXX... is Base64 encoded "username:password" string (without quotes).

JMeter provides HTTP Authorization Manager to it should be easy to set it up.

If your use case assumes multiple logins with different users - you may with to consider adding [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager) instead. You can calculate Base64-encoded value for username and password pair via __Beanshell or __javascript function or keep them in CSV file - whatever is the easiest.